# Unable to use facebook connect application on IE8: xd_receiver popup does not close

Tags: internet-explorer-8, facebook

In both Opera and Firefox, my facebook connect application successfully loads xd_receiver and everything works.  In IE8, it loads xd_receiver in the popup as expected, but the popup does not close and the data is not transmitted to my app.  The url the popup is visiting is the correct xd_receiver page, as is hinted by the fact that everything works in Firefox and Opera.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because I was testing locally.  IE8 had some special security rules that tend to break local apps.

Answer (score 2):

For IE8:

Tools > Internet Options > Security > Local Intranet > Sites (Button) > Automatically Detect...

-> uncheck this, then it works fine

grrr IE8!